# How to open webpage without localhost

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm currently using live server on VSCode to test and run my webpage, now i wanna sent it to other people. The problem is using only the web browser there are some bugs saying that "URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request." which makes my website can't fetch

Comment: Use a service like ngrok

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I am wrong but I am pretty sure that when you run live server on VSCode it only means that you can access the webpage or "localhost" if you are connected to your network.

So in short if you want other people to view your projects you need to host it somewhere. There are some good free hosting services which you can use, some that I can think about are Github Pages, Firebase, Netlify, Heroku and Vercel.

I hope this answers your question, if not I will happily answer some more ;)

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation but is there anyway for me to just send them the html, js files + assets folders and the other guy can just view it without localhost? because when I try it myself i got  the "URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request."

Comment: Sending the html, js and assets files will mostly not work as it will require the other person to setup and different machines can cause different issues. If you really want to showcase a project the way is to host it unless you want to use a screen recorder and send the video.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is easy and fast for use, you can use ngrok to public your URL of the current webpage that generates from ngrok for everyone can open your webpage. Just download you will get instruction from ngrok directly (link: https://ngrok.com), and the last choice you need you to deploy your code to Heroku, Netlify, etc.

Comment: thanks but is there anyway for me to just send them the html, js files + assets folders and the other guy can just view it without localhost? because when I try it myself i got the "URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request."

Comment: u need to use GitHub or bitbucket to push your source code to the public, so anyone will be can see your code easily.